# prometheus max limit for counters

Tags: prometheus

When using counters in prometheus, would we ever hit the problem of reaching the max limit for the counter (assuming the application never restarts) ? If so, would it affect the underlying application that is trying to expose the metric or would it be taken care by prometheus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the declaration of `counter` metrics type from  `prometheus/client_golang`.

```golang
type counter struct {
    // valBits contains the bits of the represented float64 value, while
    // valInt stores values that are exact integers. Both have to go first
    // in the struct to guarantee alignment for atomic operations.
    // http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#pkg-note-BUG
    valBits uint64
    valInt  uint64

    selfCollector
    desc *Desc

    labelPairs []*dto.LabelPair
}
```

They used `unsigned int64` type for `valInt` counter. So once it exceeds the limit of `int64`, it will be set to `zero` again. I guess it will be similar for other client libraries too.